# How can I maximize my Magic Find?

Tags: diablo-iii

What should I wear to maximize my Magic Find? What specific items are ideal for a Magic Find-optimized build? Does any one particular class have better class-specific items with increased Magic Find?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maximum **soft capacity** for magic find  in **2.0.1.** remains at **300%**...Soft capacity is the maximum % of magic find that player can accumulate with items on him and follower,it does not include buffs and bonuses.

Hard capacity is calculated maximum possible magic find.Which **was at 680%** prior to the 2.0.1.
Since then **paragon levels** don't reward magic find anymore,**nephalem valor** is removed from the game and **monster power** level doesn’t increase magic find(it does give you better legendary items but it is not calculated in magic find) we are left with:

- +10% per player from Strength in numbers buff (max +30% with full party).
- +25% shrine of fortune.

Making **hard cap for MF 355%**

This ~50% MF reduction would seem drastic,but i doesn't really matter that much anymore since **MF in 2.0.1. is almost useless** because your magic find now affects :

- 100% for blue items,
- 30% for rares
- and only 10% for Legendary/Set items

For more info on gear slots and items you should check **Wikwocket**’s answer which stays pretty much valid except for nephalem valor.
Writing more detailed and updated list of best possible items for magic find really doesn’t matter anymore,even if you managed somehow to get more than 300% MF from items it wouldn’t count,and i really doubt someone would sacrifice all the stats for **mere max 35% MF on Legendary/Set items.**

[Source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/10895540027?page=15)
,[Source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/8568890869?page=1)

Comment: Note that when actually playing on average cvharacters you will encounter more legendary items and all other items will fit better to your hero...But this has nothing to do with player Magic Find it is because they changed the way items will drop from client side.

Comment: Also Blizzard stated that they are trying to reduce Magic find to make it more fair and give players more equal chances of getting very good items,which should be much harder to obtain now.

Answer (score 16):

### As of [patch 1.0.4  the maximum Magic Find is now capped at **300%**](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6968517).  The only exception is Nephalem Valor which can bring the total Magic Find to 375%.

Pre-patch info:

Here is an attempt at a max-possible magic-find percentage:

Gear slots:

- Amulet slot: **40%**
- All other slots except weapon: 11 * 20% = **220%** (head, shoulders, torso, wrists, hands, waist, legs, feet, 2x rings, offhand) (Note: ring are limited to 18)
- Helmet gem slot: **31%** ([Radiant Star Topaz](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/radiant-star-topaz))
- Follower amulet slot: 40% * 20% follower bonus ratio = **8%**
- Follower ring and offhand slots: (2 * 18% + 20%) * 20% follower bonus ratio = **11%**
- [Nephalem Valor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66122/how-does-the-nephalem-valor-buff-work): **75%**
- Shrine of Fortune: **25%**

**Total: 410%**

Notable Legendaries with magic find.  Note you can equip followers with them too:

- Sun Keeper (up to 50%)
- The Grand Vizier (up to 45%)

Classes:

- No class has an advantage because magic find does not appear on magic items. It does appear on off-hands, which all classes can wield.
- To my knowledge, no class has abilities that affect magic find. If Blizzard implemented this, it would massively skew class distribution, as everyone would play that class for the advantage.
- Barbarians do have a related ability, [Threatening Shout w/ Grim Harvest](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/barbarian/active/threatening-shout), but I believe this just makes monsters drop more things on average, without affecting the quality of the drops.

Overall, to maximize profit, I think you would do better optimizing for your class's DPS stats, and adding in as much gold find and magic find as you can without hurting your kill rate or survivability.

Comment: Barbarian has an ability that increases magic find (Threatening shout - Grim harvest)

Comment: @Anders Good catch, although I don't think Grim Harvest affects drop quality, only drop frequency. I added it in.

Comment: pretty sure amulets only goes up to 40%, haven't seen any amulet with higher than 40% mf

Comment: and there are also weapons that give magic find

Comment: @yx. I've updated the post with some info on weapon/amulet/ring MF, which makes for a higher total.

Comment: Witch Doctors may actually have a slight advantage, as there is a set piece ceremonial knife [which can have up to 35% MF](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/manajumas-ritual-cutter). This allows WDs to use a weapon with 10% more MF than the highest MF available on a non class-specific [weapon](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/sun-keeper).

Comment: @Beofett Good point. The player "ImmortalSpawn" that I linked to was indeed using a Witch Doctor, for this reason.

Comment: As of the 1.04 patch, magic find is hard-capped at 300%.  This includes the bonus from Paragon levels, but does not include the bonus from Nephalem Valor (so that can still add an additional 75%).

Comment: @Wikwocket Any chance you could update, per bwarner's comment. Your previous well researched and sourced answer is now a little out of date.

Answer (score 8):

You should always wear items with the highest % magic find you can.

Magic Find is an affix just like anything else, and since the vast majority of Diablo III loot is random, so too is the Magic Find you will, well, find.

Discounting the legendary items (the only class-specific items with pre-defined stats), because they are hard to come by, we are left with the entire array of basic items useable by any class that can have the +magic find affix.

Now, scanning the list of magical affixes that are floating around ([like this one](http://www.diablofans.com/topic/41045-diablo-iii-item-affixes/#entry863906)), there are two separate (but identically named) affixes, one for Amulets, and one for Ring/Armor/Offhand (Essentially, everything but weapons). So right there is a big clue that no class gets better magic find for its class specific items - because *everyone*'s class-specific armor is still *armor*, they share the potential for the lower-magnitude "Find Magic %".

So if you want to wear the highest % magic find you can, and no exclusive items are better at that, what else is there left to do?

Well, the thing about % magic find is that it's taking up an affix on your items... which means any item with % magic find on it is makes your character less powerful than an equivalent item which rolled +damage or +armor instead. If your character is dying, you're not finding *any* items, so to maximize your chance to find items, you want to find the sweet spot between your maximum % magic find and your "not dying to monsters" state.

Finally, once you hit level 60, seek out Rares and Champions for Nephalem Valor. Nephalem Valor is a stacking buff of % magic find, and there's no penalty to it (though if you change spells you lose the buff).

**NOTE: As of 1.0.4 magic find is no longer averaged across a party.**

<strike>If you have low magic find, find a buddy.</strike>

If you have high magic find, go solo.

Magic Find is averaged across a party. If you've got 300% magic find, and your partner's got a measely 10%, you guys are at at effective 155% magic find.

Comment: Woah had no idea magic find would be the average of the party, interesting.

Comment: It has come to my attention that magic find has some manner of diminishing returns. While this might make it harder to reach higher and higher amounts of magic find, and while it *should* affect gearing decisions, **maximizing** magic find still involves stacking all of it you can, diminishing returns be damned.

Comment: *"Magic Find is averaged across a party"* - this appears to be not true.  This myth is repeated all over the internet, but they all link back to the [same post](http://goo.gl/nYDqx) by a Blizzard employee, which is self-contradictory:  *"The amount displayed is your share of the bonus [..] Magic Find is averaged across the entire group."*  This means everyone in the group should have the same magic-find displayed; however, they do not.  And [anecdotally](http://goo.gl/aGl8B), party members with differing magic-find see an **extreme** difference in the items they find.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Averaging the magic find across the group wouldn't change the displayed magic find. Anecdata is the worst kind of data when you're trying to refute something.

Comment: @Raven: According to the same post that claims magic-find is averaged, the magic-find displayed in the details tab is *"your share of the magic find."*  If that were true, then your displayed magic find should change when people enter or leave your party; however, it does not.  If that part of the source is false, why should we believe the other thing written there (that magic find is averaged), especially since it conflicts with the experiences everyone is reporting?  Perhaps we need a more scientific study of this effect?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft It *is* your share of the magic find. As in, the Magic Find you, yourself, are contributing. The problem is that you're assuming all the shares are equal. They're not.

Comment: Its not averaged I find more rares on hell mode then a lvl 59 hero with nv 5 stacks then they ask me why do I get so much rares