# What is the best way to maximize gold find in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

What is the best way to maximize your gold find? Some items have extra gold find and if you socket correctly you can get gold find on that too. What is the highest gold find percentage you can get and which items, spells, gems do you need to get that? Are there any classes that change this too?

Comment: I would vote to reopen this if I could... the answer below is a great checklist of things to look for if you're trying to maximize your gold drops. Perhaps you can edit your question a bit so it asks for a canonical list of how to maximize your gold drops, and doesn't just ask what the highest gold find % is?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### As of [patch 1.0.4  the maximum gold find is now capped at **300%**](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6968517).  The only exception is Nephalem Valor which can bring the total Gold Find to 375%.

Pre patch information:

According to datamining sites ([example](http://www.diablofans.com/topic/41045-spoiler-diablo-iii-item-affixes/#entry863906)) the relevant item affixes are:

- **Amulet:** Prosperous: Chance to Find Gold Increases by 41-50%
- **Ring/Armor/Offhand:** Prosperous: Chance to Find Gold Increases by 21-25%

So, here is a try at the most possible gold find.

- Amulet slot: **50%**
- All other slots except weapon: 11 * 25% = **275%** (head, shoulders, torso, wrists, hands, waist, legs, feet, 2x rings, offhand)
- Helmet gem slot: **31%** (Radiant Star Emerald)
- Follower amulet slot: 50% * 20% follower bonus ratio = **10%**
- Follower ring and offhand slots: 3 * 25% * 20% follower bonus ratio = **15%**
- [Nephalem Valor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66122/how-does-the-nephalem-valor-buff-work): **75%**
- Shrine of Fortune: **25%**
- Demon Hunter [Ferret Companion](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/companion): **10%**

**Total: 491%**

There may be some legendaries with increased gold find, so more than this may be possible. However this is not at all realistic, because 1) it would take ages to find perfect "Prosperous" items for all these slots, and 2) your gear would likely be decidedly suboptimal for your class if all you sought was Prosperous items.

Overall, to maximize profit, I think you would do better optimizing for your class's DPS stats, and adding in as much gold find and magic find as you can without hurting your kill rate or survivability.

Comment: Don't forget jewel slots

Comment: @ChrisRasys Thanks, added in the helm gem slot (the only one to add gold find I believe).

Comment: Also, DH has an skill+rune that increase his gold find. If you take that in count.

Comment: Also, don't forget the Valor buff. I think that's 75% assuming you have a full stack of 5.

Comment: @Mr.November Valor buff == [Nephalem Valor buff](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66122/how-does-the-nephalem-valor-buff-work)?

Comment: @Mr.November Added that in. Checking class skills now.

Comment: @MichelAyres yes

Comment: @MichelAyres Added in the DH skill. Together we will ferret out the truth to this answer.

Comment: @Wikwocket \o/ To the best answer and beyond!

Comment: Do you know if most of those same values would apply to Magic Find as well? And if not, would you be willing to post a similar answer to the question about [maximizing your Magic Find](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/66216/8462)? It's a very nice checklist of things to look for when building a Magic/Gold finding set :)

Comment: @Rachel The calculations for MF would be similar. I'll work on a list for the other question.

Comment: Shouldn't the follower's ring/offhand bonuses be 3 * 25% * 20% = 15%? Also, the Nephalem Valor post says nothing about gold find being affected, so if your 100% NV bonus is correct, you should also give an answer or comment there. (Only thing stated there is that it gives +75% magic find and +5 boss drops when maxed.)

Comment: @TheodoreMurdock Thanks, I noticed too that as I wrote the MF post, and fixed it. As for NV, [everything](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4241234476#1) I've [read](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4309851977) says it affects gold find as well, including the post I link to.

Comment: @Wikwocket The Nephalem Valor post was finally updated to the correct value of 75%

Comment: Just wanted to make a note about "Overall, to maximize profit, I think you would do better optimizing for your class's DPS stats". There are some spots (The Royal Crypts for example) where on a typical run you will encounter 3 skeletons and find 6-7k gold (on hell with 154% GF. that would be nearly 20k with max GF). So DPS doesn't matter here.

Comment: Actually there is one more way to improve your gold find. There are two rings that together form a set. The rings are called "Screaming chain" and "Band of fallen heroes" and if you have them both they provide a set bonus of +15 gold find and +15 magic find. The rings themselves can have 18 gold find (as they are level 61 rings). So in total you could get +51 gold find on the two rings instead off +40 on two +20 rings which is +11 more in gold find.

Comment: Can we get updated values added to this answer with info from patch 1.0.5, specifically regarding Monster Power.  People will probably ask regarding how MP +MF/GF affects the 300/375 (+25) cap.

Comment: With patch 2.0.1, some of the major sources of gold find have been reworked.  The tooltip still says there is a max of 300%, but Torment difficulties offer a bonus beyond that (I assume they're exempt from the cap, but cannot confirm - but it's silly to give a +550% bonus and then cap you at 300%).  Paragon bonuses have also been reworked and there's a category just for increasing gold find.  Is the Paragon bonus exempt from the cap too?

Answer (score 2):

I hate to make another answer, but the previous answer is wrong.

Maximum value gold find per slot is presently:
Amulet: 40%
Ring: 20%
2H Sword: 25% (Sultan of the Burning Sands legendary)
Quiver: 20%
Shield: 25%
Other Armor: 25%

So, the 8 'common' armor slots cap at 200%.

With a legendary 2H sword, you can get another 25%.
 
With any 1H and a cap shield, you can get 25%.
With any ranged and a cap quiver, you can get 20%.

**Breakdown**

Due to quivers having slightly less, the ferrets available bring it up 10%, which makes a demon hunter with quiver and ferrets cap at 30%; or demon hunter with 1h xbow, ferrets, and shield cap at 35%.

The helmet socket is the only socket that can provide additional find. 
A radiant star emerald can provide 31% additional gold find, though most will only use a 25% as it's the highest you can make without getting a dropped recipe.

The most effective follower is either the templar (with cap gold find shield) or the enchantress (with a cap Sultan of the Burning Sands), two rings, and an amulet.. all at cap. The bonus you get is 20% of theirs, with their cap being (25+20+20+40)/5=21%.

For a demon hunter with 2H ranged equipped, the equipment bonus caps at: 
200% (armor) + 10% ferrets + 20% quiver + 31% radiant star emerald + 21% follower + 80% jewelery = 362%.

For a demon hunter with 1H xbow and shield equipped, the equipment bonus caps at: 
200% (armor) + 10% ferrets + 25% shield + 31% radiant star emerald + 21% follower + 80% jewelery = 367%.

For all other classes, if they have a shield equipped, the bonus caps at:
200% (armor) + 25% shield + 31% radiant star emerald + 21% follower + 80% jewelery = 357%.

For classes who can use a 2H sword and ignore shield, the Sultan build caps at:
200% (armor) + 25% sultan + 31% radiant star emerald + 21% follower + 80% jewelery = 357%.

If you have 5 stacks of NV, it provides 75% more. A fortune shrine adds 25%.

**Summary**

So maximum possible gold find is a 1h xbow wielding demon hunter with ferrets and a shield, a capped follower, with 5 NV stacks and a fortune shrine, which can net 467%.

If they use a quiver, and thereby allowing a 2H ranged to clear faster, they are limited to 462%

All other classes, if using a shield, or that particular 2H sword, are limited to 457%.

Without a shield or that particular legendary sword, then all other classes cap at 432%.