# Max gold find %?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to maximize gold find in Diablo 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68506/what-is-the-best-way-to-maximize-gold-find-in-diablo-3)

Is there a maximum cap for gold find in Diablo 3?

Does Gold Find go above 100% for a character?

If so, does that mean i will get more gold or an increased chance for monsters to drop gold?

Comment: does that mean there's a max cap?

Comment: There is no cap. You just can't find better gear.

Comment: also, that other link says increased gold find may drop legendaries... i thought that was magic find?

Comment: No. Read again =)