# Is there now a cap on Gold Find % in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to maximize gold find in Diablo 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68506/what-is-the-best-way-to-maximize-gold-find-in-diablo-3)

According to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/68540/2252) the maximum gold find in Diablo 3 is **491%**:

> - Amulet slot: **50%**
> - All other slots except weapon: 11 * 25% = **275%** (head, shoulders, torso, wrists, hands, waist, legs, feet, 2x rings, offhand)
> - Helmet gem slot: **31%** (Radiant Star Emerald)
> - Follower amulet slot: 50% * 20% follower bonus ratio = **10%**
> - Follower ring and offhand slots: 3 * 25% * 20% follower bonus ratio = **15%**
> - [Nephalem Valor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66122/how-does-the-nephalem-valor-buff-work):
>     **75%**
> - Shrine of Fortune: **25%**
> - Demon Hunter [Ferret Companion](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/companion):
>     **10%**
>
> **Total: 491%**

However when I was playing this weekend, comeone in the `[general]` chat asked if **300%** was the max. I responded that 491% was the maximum and they asked why their GF% wouldn't increase above 300%.

I suspect this changed around the time that the Goldskin (+100% Gold Find body armor) and Puzzle Ring were introduced. That would have raised the max GF% to **565%** which is * ridiculous*.

Is Gold Find now capped at 300% in Diablo 3?

Comment: There is no reason to ask this again.  It is 100% covered by the question you linked to.

Comment: I made the patch 1.04 info more visible, so now this question can be closed as duplicate

Comment: @OrigamiRobot the other answer was incorrect. I asked this question to confirm details before I edited the other answer.

Comment: @yx Yes, this can be closed as a duplicate, but can't be *deleted* as the link you just edited links back *here* :-)

Comment: You can't ask a duplicate question in order to answer a previous question.

Comment: @Josh I noticed that, but usually dupes aren't deleted so there should be no issues.

Comment: the best course at this time is to ask a mod to merge the 2 questions imo

Comment: @yx. I changed the link to the original blog post confirming the cap.  No merge required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a [**blue post**](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/6413171867#15) from the official Diablo 3 forums:

> The Magic Find and Gold Find percentages for both follower contributions and Fortune Shrine bonuses are intended to respect the 300% MF/GF cap. Nephalem Valor bonuses will continue to stack beyond this cap, however.
>
> That said, we’ve seen some posts that MF/GF contributions from followers may currently be stacking above the cap, and we’re looking into those reports.

Another more visible place where this was announced is the [**blog post**](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6968517/Introducing_the_Paragon_System-8_20_2012) that first introduced the Paragon leveling system.

> With the Paragon system in place, we’re capping Magic Find and Gold Find to 300% (before Nephalem Valor).

So yes, the gold cap is 300% before Nephalim Valor and cannot be exceeded with followers or shrines.

Comment: Ah ha, thanks for the definitive link! Too bad, I wanted to get to 565% Gold Find. You know, just to say that i did :-)

Answer (score 5):

The cap on Gold and Magic Find Bonuses is now 300%, as of the 1.0.4 patch. This is before Nephalem Valor is factored in. With a full stack of NV, Gold and Magic Find bonuses can get up to 375%.

This change was made as part of the [Paragon System](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6968517/Introducing_the_Paragon_System-8_20_2012) introduced in Patch 1.0.4.

The linked article includes rationale for the change, if you are interested. The relevant section is titled "… What Was That About Magic Find On Items?"