# How do I find a Triumvirate?

Tags: diablo-iii

The Triumvirate unique item looks to be an incredible pick up for a level ~40 Wizard. Some are also socketed. I am not familiar with how uniques are found in Diablo 3, as in whether they can be crafted, dropped more frequently by certain monsters or quests, or something else. Anything I can do to raise my chances would be good knowledge to have.

[image: Trimumvirate in-game image]

Comment: Magic Find for a slightly better chance.  To be guaranteed to get it, auction house.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, [Triumvirate](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/triumvirate) cannot be crafted. Some unique and set items can be crafted in D3, but not this one, as it's official Battle.net page shows.

Therefore the only ways to get this item is by getting it to drop, or buying it on the auction house.

You can wear [lots of magic find](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66216/how-can-i-maximize-my-magic-find) to improve your chances of finding uniques, but at this point we don't know the loot drop formulas to know where to farm for an item if you are looking for a specific drop: certain monsters in certain difficulties can drop items of different type and level, but we don't know what these rules are (yet).

So your best bet is to search for it regularly on the AH. You can ask friends to keep an eye out for it too, offer a bounty if anyone finds one, advertise in general chat, and so on. You can of course farm other rare and unique items to offer in trade, or to sell so you have the money to snatch up Triumvirate when it appears!

Comment: Yeah I knew from experience with Diablo 1 that certain items have qlvl and clvl restrictions for dropping/buying, just wasn't sure if they were publicly known yet for D3. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "definite" way of hunting for a Triumvirate. You could always go down the magic find path and increase your chances of mobs dropping the Legendary, or you could always hit the Auction House to trade money for items.

Also, Blizzard has made it clear that in Diablo 3, Rares may also surpass random properties of Legendaries, so why fix your target on one item when you could random so much more?

Comment: Agreed.  The only legendary I've had drop was a level 47 monk fist (I actually had two drop... go figure!).  I gave one to a monk friend who had just hit 47.  The next day he told me he had outleveled it, and wanted to know if I wanted it back.  They are great if you have someone who can use it immediately, but not worth putting a ton of effort into obtaining simply because they don't last long (until you get the level 60 legendaries).