# Chances to get Rare Items

Tags: diablo-iii

You're probably expecting a 'rage' post about never getting Rare's, but it's the contrary.

I've been playing for the past few days with a friend, and I seem to get a rare item on an average of 10 minutes per piece. Whereas my friend only gets rare pieces when it comes to boss levels.

Being a DH, and my friend a Monk, is there any class that by default gets rare pieces more frequently than others? Or certain levels, bosses?

Comment: The only difference I am aware of is that [your chance of getting a rare item is much higher the first time you kill a boss on normal](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/67417/8462). Has one of you already gone through and killed the bosses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rare drop base is the same across all classes however it can be affected by gear and Magic % drop rates on the gear or followers.