# What is the requirement to give my party members the Nephlem bonus?

Tags: diablo-iii

To make sure every member in my party gets the bonus what are the requirements?

Does each person have to:

- be alive?
- hit the mob?
- be in the range of the buff (if there is a range)?
- be in the same area?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the Nephalem Valor buff work?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66122/how-does-the-nephalem-valor-buff-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I did a quick test of this with another Level 60 character in a Hell Game.

To receive the Nephlem valor buff you must be involved in the combat. You do get the buff if you are in town or dead if you were involved in the combat. So, you don't have to wait on your friend to get done healing while you finish the monster. You also don't have to resurrect your ally before finishing the fight.

You do not receive it when:

- You are standing next to the monster when it dies but don't help/participate in the combat.
- You are in town or across the map during the entire combat (again, because you weren't a member of the combat)

Answer (score 0):

Every time you kill a champion or elite pack at level 60, you will get 1 stack of this buff, the buff lasts 30 minutes and can be stacked 5 times, which at max will grant you 75% extra magic find and gold find.

If you kill another pack as mentioned the timer will reset and you will gain a stack. The buff will disappear if you change skills, remove a skill from the skill bar, leave the game or change acts.