# Does the Nephalem Valor buff affect the whole group (regardless of level)?

Tags: diablo-iii

When playing Diablo III with a friend who's level 60 (I'm level 59), he would acquire the Nephalem Valor buff as we would farm mobs. However despite being present for the entire duration of every fight, there was no indicator on my screen that I had received the buff. Here's my two part question:

1. Does the Nephalem Valor buff affect the entire group if others are not present for the fight (in party, in a different zone, etc).
2. Can the Nephalem Valor buff be applied to non-level-60s in the group if there is at least one level 60 present for the fight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nephalem Valor only functions for level 60s. You also [must have been involved in the fight against the Champion or Elite](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68734/what-is-the-requirement-to-give-my-party-members-the-nephlem-bonus) to receive the buff, but you do not have to be present at the actual time of the kill.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that second question when I searched for an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. The buff is applied only to those who were involved in the fight and engaged in combat (must be level 60 to receive the buff).
2. See above. Non-60 level players do not receive the buff, however, with the way magic find works, technically everyone would benefit from someone gaining the magic find buff. See https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/66177/25862 for info on magic find.