# Do followers always announce unique/champion/elite monsters?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have noticed while playing that followers tend to say something like "Look at the size of that beast" or things of that nature when a unique/champion/elite monster is near.  Is this dialog triggered 100% of the time, or only sometimes?  I'm interested in using this as an aid later in the game when trying to maintain the [Nephalem Valor buff](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66122/how-does-the-nephalem-valor-buff-work) - when it is critical to be hacking down every unique/champion/elite monster in sight (including those in sight of my follower).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's triggered almost all the time you encounter a Rare/Champion pack is visible.  I say almost all the time because I have noticed instances where my follower has not announced them.  I am yet to determine whether that is due to an internal cooldown from him talking previously or if he simply does not announce it 100% of the time.

I have also noticed a single time where he used one of his sayings usually reserved for after a fight with a Rare/Champion pack after a normal battle, as this threw me (I was not expecting it).  However this was post-fight, so should not affect your concern.

In conclusion, their sayings are a good way to indicate a Rare/Champion pack is near, but their silence may not mean an absence of said packs.

Comment: As I've focused on this more, it is really turning out to be helpful - thanks.  I have found occasions where the follower calls them out when they are off screen (to me), and a short search around allows me to find them.