# Does killing more monsters give better drops?

Tags: diablo-iii

Do you get better, or more rare, drops when you kill multiple monsters? Or is it all based on the type and level of monster you kill?

Comment: Killing more monsters gives you *more* drops, thereby indirectly improving your chances of getting a better drop.  But, so does magic find.

Comment: Related: Once you're level 60, you build up a Nephalem Valor buff by killing rare & elite packs. [That buff makes more and better loot drop](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/66122/3062)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loot is based on the level and status (champion, elite, etc) of the monster. The sheer number that you kill at one time doesn't increase drops over what you'd normally see from killing them one at a time.