# What are the hidden effects of the nephalem valor buff?

Tags: diablo-iii

The buff is explained in this question: [How does the Nephalem Valor buff work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66122/how-does-the-nephalem-valor-buff-work). It is said that there are `hidden effects`, and I'd like to know those.

From diablo.incgamers.com ([Nephalem Valor > Magic Find... MF is Broken](http://diablo.incgamers.com/forums/showthread.php?832044-Nephalem-Valor-gt-Magic-Find-MF-is-Broken))

> I used 140MF without NV buff and went to kill Zoltan Kull and he drop
>   non of yellow in 10 games.  When I have 0 MF and stack of Nephalem
>   Valor (5) 75% mf I'm getting 1-3 yellow and 3-5 blues.

---

I experience the same effect: if I do siegebreaker runs with magic find gear switch, I am up to 130% mf, and I still have poorer loot that when I kill him with 5 stacks at 75% mf. So what are the hidden effects of the NV buff ?

Comment: The question you linked to explains what Nephalem Valor does.  More stacks = more loot.  It doesn't just add extra magic find; that's a bonus.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[This Blizzard Post on the upcoming patch](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/blog/5055288/Patch_103_Design_Preview-06_06_2012#blog)  Aptly describes the hidden benefit of the Nephalem Valor buff and the changes coming to it.  (It's roughly 1/5th of the way down the post, "The Nephalem Difference")

Ahhhh screw it, here's the quote:

> "It’s no secret that our goal for the end-game item hunt is players
>   hunting monsters packs, building to five stacks of Nephalem Valor, and
>   then killing a boss. While we’re seeing a lot of that occurring, what
>   we’re missing is people feeling like it’s worthwhile to continue
>   onward after killing a boss. To help hit that goal we’re lowering the
>   number of guaranteed Rare items on bosses when you have your full five
>   stacks of Nephalem Valor from two guaranteed Rares to one guaranteed
>   Rare (you still have a very good chance at multiple rares, it's just
>   no longer guaranteed). In exchange, all champion and rare packs will
>   now drop a bonus guaranteed Rare item when you have your full five
>   stacks of Nephalem Valor. The change benefits players with more
>   overall drops, and a reason to push to continue progressing."

Comment: TL;DR: after patch 1.0.3, 5 stacks = 1 guarantee rare from champs and bosses.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to increasing your magic find and gold find by 15% per stack, Blizzard have confirmed that the Nephalem Valor buff will also increase the number of items that drop from elite/unique/superunique(boss) class enemies.

In version 1.0.2 (current at the time of writing) with a full five stacks of Nephalem Valor, you are guaranteed two rares from a "Boss" (superunique) kill in addition to greatly increasing the chance that others will drop due to the additional magic find bonus.

In version 1.0.3 (going live soon, announced by Blizzard [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6262208/Patch_103_Design_Preview-6_6_2012)) this buff will be adjusted to only guarantee one rare drop from "Boss" (superunique) enemies in order to entice people to farm rare packs instead of bosses.