# Where can I find a Pool of Reflection?

Tags: diablo-iii

With the latest 2.0.1 update, a new mechanic called a [Pool of Reflection](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/157843/) has been added to the game that provides a buff that lasts across multiple logins.  Where can I find these pools?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pools of reflection are a random spawn pool that is gold in colour, similar to health shrines:

[image]

These appear randomly throughout the world.

Comment: so they spawn randomly like regular shrines?